# How to fetch all the matched rows from a Mysql table in a PHP array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am trying to get the matched rows from a table and save it in a Global Array so that I can use it in different functions.

But when I do `print_r` of that array it shows only last row.

Here is my code

```
function setCampoFeed()
 {

        echo $sql = "SELECT campofeed.tag,campofeed.registro,campofeed.valor FROM campofeed ".
        "INNER JOIN registrofeed ON registrofeed.id = campofeed.registro ".
        "WHERE registrofeed.feed='".$this->idFeed."'";

        $result= $this->localDb->execute($sql);
        $this->campoFeed= mysql_fetch_array($result)) 

 }
```

So here `campoFeed` is the array that should have all the rows of the match, but now its just having the last row.

Thanks in advance

Comment: while loop can solve your problem

Comment: @vivek you mean something like this `while($row= mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
  {
    $this->campoFeed[]=$row; 
   
  }`

Comment: mysql_fetch_array needs while loop to fetch. Also I don't think `$this->campoFeed` or `$this->campoFeed[]` can actually push data into array. I would suggest setup a array like `$resultArray = array();`. When inside while loop, `$resultArray[] = $row;`. Finally `$this->compoFeed = $resultArray;`.

Comment: @AkiEru actually $this->campoFeed is already set as array in the beginning

Comment: @Vikram, yeah I know but even you need to push data into an array, `[]` should be added and I'm not sure if `$this->campoFeed[]` is gonna work.

Comment: If `$this->campoFeed[]` works, you can use `while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { $this->campoFeed[] = $row; }` instead of creating a new array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one if it works for you..

```
$resultArray = array();
$campoFeed = array();
$resultArray = mysql_fetch_array($result);

foreach($resultArray as $key => $value){
    $campoFeed[$key] = $value;
}

print_r($campoFeed);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
$this->campoFeed[] = mysql_fetch_array($result);"
```

insted of

```
 $this->campoFeed= mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

You will get all data in array

Comment: sorry bro just tested again , its the same won't work shows only the last row

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
$mergedArray=array();
while($data= mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $final_array = unserialize($data['data']);
    $mergedArray=array_merge($mergedArray,$final_array);
}

array_unique($mergedArray, SORT_REGULAR);
```